# modified gamma integral

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function, definite-integrals

I have the following integral

$$\int_0^{+\infty} t^{z-1} e^{-t} \frac1{(kt + 1)^s}\mathrm dt$$

where $k>0, s > 0$. How would you suggest to solve it? Without $\frac1{(kt + 1)^s}$ it would be equal to $\Gamma(z)$.

Comment: Is this related to one of your [other recent questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34388/a-variation-on-the-f-distribution)?

Comment: no, it's another problem, I actually fixed a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you want.  I tried really hard for a few hours, and here are some things I derived.
Say $$I=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}\frac{1}{(kt+1)^s}dt$$

The nicest other representations I found were
$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\text{B}(s-w,w)k^{-w}\Gamma(z-w)dw$$
Where $\text{B}(x,y)$ is the beta function.  Also there is the more symmetric equation

$$I=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu^{s-1}\chi^{z-1}e^{-(\mu+\chi)}e^{-k\mu\chi}d\mu d\chi,$$ and

$$I=k^{-z}e^{\frac{1}{k}}\int_{0}^{1}\mu^{s-z-1}(1-\mu)^{z-1}e^{-\frac{1}{\mu k}}d\mu.$$

Now after the last one, and countless failed attempts I started to believe this had hypergeometric functions in it (which I have less experience with).  However, I am aware that $$\int_0^1 e^{kt}t^{s-1}(1-t)^{z-1}dt$$ is a type of hypergeometric function, and the last integral was very close to this.  Indeed, plugging everything into wolfram alpha yields $$I=k^{-s}\Gamma(z-s){}_1F_{1}\left(s;\ s-z+1;\ \frac{1}{k}\right)+\frac{k^{-z}\Gamma(z)\Gamma(s-z){}_1F_{1}\left(z;\ z-s+1;\ \frac{1}{k}\right)}{\Gamma(s)}$$  where ${}_1F_1$ is the [Confluent Hypergeometric Series of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).

Hope that helps,

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort! I guess I will need to buy mathematica for future needs

Comment: @bob:  Actually it is free online: http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: In my case wolfram doesn't find any result. which equation did you plug in?

Comment: @Bob: The same one.  At first it didn't work, and timed out, but there is a button you can click to give it more time, and then it worked.

Comment: Teeny note: ${}_1 F_1$ is the (Kummer) confluent hypergeometric function; $F_1$ is a different hypergeometric beast altogether.

Comment: I guess that you have to assume that $z-s$ is not in Z otherwise gamma functino diverges

Comment: @Bob: that's why using Tricomi instead of Kummer here is profitable; the expression using Kummer has (removable) singularities. In the Tricomi solution, the only restriction is that $z$ not be a nonpositive integer.

Answer (score 5):

If you formally insert the binomial series

$$(1+kt)^{-s}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(s)_j}{j!}(-kt)^j$$

into your integral, swap summation and integration, and integrate termwise (whose validity can be justified with [Watson's lemma](http://books.google.com/books?id=aTPZmnz4uGsC&pg=PA48), but I shall skip the justification), we arrive at the formally divergent series

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(s)_j}{j!}(-k)^j \Gamma(z+j)=\Gamma(z){}_2 F_0(s,z;;-k)$$

The trick here is that the divergent hypergeometric series ${}_2 F_0(a,b;;z)$ can be formally shown to correspond to an asymptotic series for the integral mentioned in the OP, and can also be related to the (more familiar?) [Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricU/) $U(a,b,z)$, the other standard solution to the [second-order differential equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E1) satisfied by the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function mentioned in Eric's answer.

More directly, using a [certain integral representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.4.E4) for the Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function, we have the ["identity"](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.6.E21)

$${}_2 F_0(s,z;;-k)=k^{-s} U\left(s,1+s-z,\frac1{k}\right)=k^{-z} U\left(z,1+z-s,\frac1{k}\right)$$

The closed form $\Gamma(z)k^{-z} U\left(z,1+z-s,\frac1{k}\right)$ can then be shown to be equivalent to the expression in Eric's answer via [this identity](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E42) connecting the Kummer and Tricomi functions. (A justification is sketched in [this reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=7dQko2CndYoC&pg=PA175).)

Comment: Nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_0^{\infty}t^{z - 1}\expo{-t}\,{1 \over \pars{kt + 1}^{s}}\,\dd t:\
     {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_0^{\infty}t^{z - 1}\expo{-t}\,%
> {1 \over \pars{kt + 1}^{s}}\,\dd t}
> =\int_0^{\infty}t^{z - 1}\pars{1 + {t \over 1/k}}^{-s}\expo{-t}\,\dd t
> \end{align}

By following the $\ds{\tt\mbox{MathWorld}}$ definition $\pars{5}$ of the [Whittaker Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WhittakerFunction.html):
$$
\mbox{}-q - \half + m = z - 1\,,\quad\mbox{}q - \half + m = -s\quad
\mbox{we get}\quad
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
q & = & {1 - z - s \over 2}
\\[2mm]
m & = & {z - s \over 2}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then,

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_0^{\infty}t^{z - 1}\expo{-t}\,%
> {1 \over \pars{kt + 1}^{s}}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&=\Gamma\pars{\half - {1 - z - s \over 2} + {z - s \over 2}}\,
> {1 \over \expo{-\pars{1/k}/2}}\,{1 \over \pars{1/k}^{\pars{1 - z - s}/2}}
> {\rm W}_{\pars{1 - z -s}/2,\ \pars{z - s}/2}\pars{1 \over k}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_0^{\infty}t^{z - 1}\expo{-t}\,%
{1 \over \pars{kt + 1}^{s}}\,\dd t}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\exp\pars{1 \over 2k}k^{\pars{1 - z - s}/2}\
\Gamma\pars{z}{\rm W}_{\pars{1 - z -s}/2,\ \pars{z - s}/2}\pars{1 \over k}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\rm W}$ is the $\ds{\tt\mbox{Whittaker Function}}$.